# How to convert PNG image to GIF in iPhone programmatically

Tags: iphone, objective-c, png, gif

How to picker some pictures from the library, and convert them to a gif?

Comment: Any Success on the same? Already some app doing this. I need same thing. Can you help me ?

Answer (score 1):

Check these Links

According to Apple,

> Xcode automatically optimizes your PNG images using the pngcrush
>   utility shipped with the SDK. (You’ll find the program in the iPhoneOS
>   platform folders in /Developer. Run it  from the command line with the
>   –iphoneswitch to convert standard PNG files to iPhone- formatted
>   ones.) For this reason,use PNG images in your iPhone apps where
>   possible as your preferred image format.

Better prefer to use PNG's for your image requirements

For Picking Image :

http://iphone.zcentric.com/2008/08/28/using-a-uiimagepickercontroller/

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/CameraAndPhotoLib_TopicsForIOS/Articles/TakingPicturesAndMovies.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010406

For Conversion :
http://blog.objectgraph.com/index.php/2010/04/05/download-an-image-and-save-it-as-png-or-jpeg-in-iphone-sdk/

Hope this Helps

Answer (score 1):

There's ImageMagick for iPhone.Check [Using ImageMagick to create animated GIFs on the iPhone](http://brainbowapps.com/articles/2010/using-imagemagick-to-create-animated-gifs-on-the-iphone.html).
Or search "ImageMagick for iphone" at Google

Answer (score 0):

You can create a GIF using the ImageIO framework, which is part of the iOS SDK.  You don't need ImageMagick or any other third-party library.

Look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14916097/77567) for code that uses ImageIO to create an animated GIF.  If you don't want an animated GIF, just add a single image instead of a bunch of images.

As for picking images from the library, there are many questions about this already on stackoverflow.  Just search for `[iphone] pick image from library`.