# How do I save a gif to my photo album?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I've tried using UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum and ALAssetsLibrary to save my gif to the photo album. But when I try to email the gif it does not animate. I'm pretty sure the meta data is being lost when it gets saved. Does anyone know how I can preserve the gif meta data?

Thanks

Comment: Animated GIFs are not natively supported by iOS's system components. UIImage specifically does not support animated GIFs.

Comment: However, you can save gif files you get from the web or from the mail.app into the photo album

Of course, it doesn't "animate" into the gallery, but you can request them in ALAssetsLibrary, and they animate again when you email them.

Comment: Metadata is optional. That is, not required in a gif.

Answer (score 5):

Quite an old question, but it might help someone!

I use this code to save GIF in photo album and it works fine, tested by opening GIF in MailViewComposer and iMessage.

```
ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];

NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:tempPath]; // Your GIF file path which you might have saved in NSDocumentDir or NSTempDir

[library writeImageDataToSavedPhotosAlbum:data metadata:nil completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error) {
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Error Saving GIF to Photo Album: %@", error);
    } else {
        // TODO: success handling
        NSLog(@"GIF Saved to %@", assetURL);

        success(tempPath);
    }
}];
```

Comment: alas alaassetslibrary is deprecated and no longer supported in ios11!

Answer (score 0):

**GIF can be easily saved from URL to Album**

```
let url = FileManager.default.urlForFile("lion.gif") // Document Directory or Bundle url path 

PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges ({
    PHAssetChangeRequest.creationRequestForAssetFromImage(atFileURL: url)
}) { saved, error in
    if saved {
        print("Your image was successfully saved")
    }
}
```