# Convert video to GIF

Tags: iphone

I'm building an iOS app which requires me to allow the users to record a 15sec clip (with `UIImagePickerController` for example) and then convert it into an animated GIF. How could I achieve this? Is there any library/framework available for such task?

Thanks!

Comment: You can find it useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14915138/create-and-and-export-an-animated-gif-via-ios

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This gist code piece may help you.

https://gist.github.com/mayoff/4969104

It shows how to export frames into a gif image.

Answer (score 5):

I don't believe there is any existing library that would do a straight conversion for you. There's a lot of libraries for *displaying* animated GIFs - far fewer native Objective-C libraries for *creating* them.

Fortunately, iOS does have support for saving as GIFs. There's an existing StackOverflow answer that covers how to create animated GIFs in-depth here:

[Create and and export an animated gif via iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14915138/create-and-and-export-an-animated-gif-via-ios)

...there's also a library on GitHub that abstracts the lower-level stuff away, although it's not been maintained for a while ([link here](https://github.com/unixpickle/Giraffe)).

All you'll need to do is create an array of the frames you want to convert into your GIF. I *strongly* recommend you don't try and convert every single frame in your 15 second video, if only because you'll end up with a very large GIF at a frame-rate that's too high. You would be better off picking every other, or even every 3/4 frames from your video sample. Capturing images from video is also pretty well documented on iOS.

Answer (score 4):

I recently created [a library called Regift for converting videos to gifs on iOS](https://github.com/matthewpalmer/Regift). Hopefully it will help anyone coming to this in the future :)

Comment: I am having a requirement in which I need to create video from gif. how to achieve this ?