# Convert Images to gif using ios

Tags: iphone, ios

I am trying to convert 10 UIImages in .gif format programatically using IOS Xcode 4.5 and save it in gallery,  but am having no luck I even tried  a  question at stackoverflow
[Create and and export an animated gif via iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14915138/create-and-and-export-an-animated-gif-via-ios) I am not getting the point what are the variables like  __bridge id used and how can i assign these images to the method please help ....

Answer (score -2, accepted):

First of all you should check for your problem in Apple Documentation. Everything is given there. What you need is to **Research & Read**.

You should try the [ImageIO framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/graphicsimaging/Conceptual/ImageIOGuide/ikpg_dest/ikpg_dest.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005462-CH219-DontLinkElementID_2). It can convert **.png files** into `CGImageRef` objects and then export the `CGImageRefs` to **.gif files**.

To save Images to Photo Library :`UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(imageToSave, nil, nil, nil);`
Also Documented in [UIKit](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html).

Comment: Just one more thing vin here i am saving with the path  NSString *path = [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"animated.gif"]; what's the path for gallery as this is saved in the documents  folder

Comment: @naughty : What do you mean by "gallery" ?

Comment: the picturegallery folder used where all the pictures are saved when we click from camera or photos in iphone

Comment: @naughty : `UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(imageToSave, nil, nil, nil);`

Comment: Iam using something like  CGImageDestinationSetProperties(destination, (CFDictionaryRef)gifProperties);
    CGImageDestinationFinalize(destination);
    CFRelease(destination);
 to save the gif image and if i save the image using UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum it would save a still image

Comment: @naughty : Take a look at : http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html

Comment: Thanks Brother i would do that but thanks a tons for the help ;)

Answer (score 1):

instead of converting image in to Gif apple provide UIImageView.animationImages proparty that you can Animation Number of images one by one like gif. like Bellow code:-

```
UIImage *statusImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"status1.png"];
    YourImageView = [[UIImageView alloc]
                                      initWithImage:statusImage];


    //Add more images which will be used for the animation
    YourImageView.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"status1.png"],
                                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"status2.png"],
                                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"status3.png"],
                                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"status4.png"],
                                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"status5.png"],
                                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"status6.png"],
                                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"status7.png"],
                                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"status8.png"],
                                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"status9.png"],
                                         nil];




         //setFrame of postion on imageView

          YourImageView.frame = CGRectMake(
                                     self.view.frame.size.width/2
                                     -statusImage.size.width/2, 
                                     self.view.frame.size.height/2
                                     -statusImage.size.height/2, 
                                     statusImage.size.width, 
                                     statusImage.size.height);


  YourImageView.center=CGPointMake(self.view.frame.size.width /2, (self.view.frame.size.height)/2);


      YourImageView.animationDuration = 1;
      [self.view addSubview:YourImageView];
```

Comment: Thanks Nitin but in my project i am working to save the image and i don't want animation on the view i would rather upload the gif image on my servers using webservices