# GIF files in swift

Tags: ios, swift

Importing .gif file to xcode simulator by simply dragging file from system was getting converted into .png file automatically.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16996915/294884

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert Images to gif using ios](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16996690/convert-images-to-gif-using-ios)

Comment: The title of the question I've linked is not the same as yours but the accepted answers contains your solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to import gif file from Xcode's simulator camera library, make sure you download the .gif file from simulator's safari or save gif from your application to camera library.
If we import .gif file to xcode simulator by simply dragging file from system, it will automatically get converted into .png file.

```
    let savingPath : AnyObject = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory,.UserDomainMask,true)[0]

    var library:ALAssetsLibrary? = ALAssetsLibrary()
    var referenceURL : NSURL = info[UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL] as! NSURL
    library!.assetForURL(referenceURL, resultBlock: { (asset : ALAsset!) -> Void in
        var assetRep : ALAssetRepresentation = asset.defaultRepresentation()
        let sizeOfRawDataInBytes: Int = Int(assetRep.size())
        var rawData: NSMutableData = NSMutableData(length: sizeOfRawDataInBytes)!
        var bufferPtr: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void> = rawData.mutableBytes
        var bufferPtr8: UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8> = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>(bufferPtr)

        var error: NSError? = nil
        var buffered =  assetRep.getBytes(bufferPtr8, fromOffset: 0, length: sizeOfRawDataInBytes, error: &error)
        let newData: NSData = NSData(bytesNoCopy: bufferPtr8, length: buffered, freeWhenDone: false)

        newData.writeToFile( savingPath , atomically: true)
```