# How to convert video to GIF image in iPhone?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I am implementing one iPhone photo/Video application in which I have tried to implement below functionality.

Capture video through camera & convert in to GIF image

I have tried to googling but not got successed.

Can any one suggest me or advice me how to achive this feature?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You want to make a thumbnail or capture frames into an GIF animation?

Comment: I think this link may help you.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14915138/create-and-and-export-an-animated-gif-via-ios

Comment: Same issue here, Are you getting answer ?

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
#import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>
#import <MobileCoreServices/UTCoreTypes.h>
```

and use following delegate method of `UIImagePickerViewController`

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
   if ([[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaType ] isEqualToString:@"public.movie"])
   {
     MPMoviePlayerController *player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];];
        UIImage  *thumbnail = [player thumbnailImageAtTime:1.0 timeOption:MPMovieTimeOptionNearestKeyFrame];
        [player stop];
        player = nil;

     // Here your got UIImage name is 'thumbnail'
   }
}
```

You can get image ***(thumbnail)*** from video.

Comment: this is not what the question was about, it was how to convert video to gif animation, not how to capture an image from video (I assume at least).

Comment: Wrong answer not related to question

Answer (score 0):

Though this question is old, I created a library for [converting videos to gifs](https://github.com/matthewpalmer/Regift) for iOS.

Comment: Whats about Objective c?