# Create an animated movie of a UIVIew - perhaps using snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates

Tags: ios, uiview, screenshot, animated-gif, snapshot

In iOS 7 it is quite easy to create a screen shot using the new snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates UIView method.

I would like to create a screen recording using this (perhaps a different method is better). The finial outcome should be an an animated gif - or something that can be exported and viewed in a media player.

Any suggested method to do this?

Comment: Have you gone through [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14915138/create-and-and-export-an-animated-gif-via-ios/14916097#14916097)?

Comment: Nope, Didn't do any work on that. Was hoping there was a library for it somewhere