# Animated gif images

Tags: ios, animation

I have an array of images. I want to convert that images into animated gif images.
please give me some suggestion. Here is my code:

```
NSMutableArray *imgAry =[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
for(int i =0 ;i<arrFiles.count-7;i++){
    [imgAry addObject:[arrImageCache objectAtIndex:i]];
}
NSLog(@"%@",imgAry);
UIActivityViewController * activities = [[UIActivityViewController alloc]
                                         initWithActivityItems:imgAry
                                         applicationActivities:nil];
activities.excludedActivityTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:, nil];

[self presentViewController:activities
                   animated:YES
                 completion:nil];
```

Nslog of imgAry is

```
(
    "<UIImage: 0xd082f60>",
    "<UIImage: 0xd083540>",
    "<UIImage: 0xd06af80>"
)
```

Comment: What do you want? Convert the image file to .gif? Or just animate the images of imgAry?

Comment: want to conert image file in to gif

Answer (score 1):

I dont no wy u need activity controller, there is one way u can animate a series of images in the UIImageView, it looks like gif.

for example

```
  NSMutableArray *Imgarray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

  for(int i=0;i<[Imgarray  count];i++)
  {
    [array addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"myGiffImaf%d.png",i]]];
  }


  self.imageView.animationImages = Imgarray;
  self.imageView.animationDuration = 3.0;
  [self.imageView startAnimating];
```

Comment: He wanted to convert to .gif. As he mentioned in comment.

Comment: @Rashad ya i saw it now, i did't see while posting the answer, so this is one way by combining all the .gif images to make it looks like  animated gif images

Comment: we use uiactivitycontroller because i want post these image in facebook

Comment: this is a good option for animated images or you can also use ".gif" image.

Answer (score -1):

You can conver to .gif. Though I can't give you direct answer but I think you should do some reading of [Image I/O](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/graphicsimaging/Conceptual/ImageIOGuide/ikpg_dest/ikpg_dest.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005462-CH219-DontLinkElementID_2). Once I saw that it can convert image format (like .png to .gif). But how you will add multiple image I am not sure about it. I think you also need 3 party tool for this. Once I worked with images and face some problem.

**EDIT:**

I think you are lucky. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14915138/create-and-and-export-an-animated-gif-via-ios/14916097#14916097) is what you are looking for.