# Save generated GIF to camera roll?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, gif, alassetslibrary

Thanks for reading.  I've created a GIF using methods from this question:

[Create and and export an animated gif via iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14915138/create-and-and-export-an-animated-gif-via-ios)

I'm trying to use the only method that appears to be able to save non JPG/PNG images to the camera roll, `ALAssetLibrary`'s `writeImageDataToSavedPhotosAlbum:metadata:completionBlock:`

I save the Gif to the temp Directory like this:

```
NSString *exportPath = [NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingString:@"/animated.gif"];
NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:exportPath isDirectory:NO];
```

Then access the `NSData` like:

```
NSData * gifData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:fileURL.absoluteString];
```

The GIF is created as I'm able to display it in a `UIImageView`, but when I try to save it, the method returns as a success (no error) but doesn't actually save (returns `Nil` for the `NSURL * assetURL` and does not appear in the camera roll).

**How can I get my GIFs to save successfully to the camera roll?**

Comment: Added 2 Solutions. First just save existing GIF to camera roll. Second uses a library (http://jitsik.com/wordpress/?p=208) to create and save GIF to camera Roll. Check my GIT fork.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the issue was that I was unable to actually grab the GIF from the file.  I switched from using `CGImageDestinationCreateWithURL` to `CGImageDestinationCreateWithData` and used a `CFMutableDataRef` to hold the Gif data.  I don't know why, but that made saving to camera roll with `writeImageDataToSavedPhotosAlbum` work.

Answer (score 11):

**

> Solution 01 : Only saving the existing GIF file to Camera Roll

**

As I understand your problem. You are able to generate a GIF file but cannot save and also view it to the Camera Roll.

So I am attaching a sample test using existing GIF File.

**Step 01.** I copied a gif IMG_0009.GIF file in my Application Document directory.

**Step 02** Than I use the below code to load this files NSData:

```
NSURL *documentsDirectoryURL = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomain:NSUserDomainMask appropriateForURL:nil create:YES error:nil];
NSURL *fileURL = [documentsDirectoryURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"IMG_0009.gif"];

NSData *gifData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[fileURL path]];
```

**Step 03:** Now I save the file in the Media Directory:

```
ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
[library writeImageDataToSavedPhotosAlbum:gifData metadata:nil completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error) {

    NSLog(@"Success at %@", [assetURL path] );
}];
```

The Asset URL is proper. Now you can check you media directory. you can locate the saved gif image.

***Have Fun :)***

---

**

> Solution 02: Demo of Creating and saving GIF to Camera roll

**

I cloned some solution to show creating and saving of GIF files to Camera Roll.
You can download and check my fork at github:

The demo creates a GIF file by taking 2 or more images and save in the Camera Roll Directory

https://github.com/bllakjakk/Giraffe

The main Code to focus is like below:

```
[export encodeToFile:tempFile callback:^(NSString * aFile) {

    NSLog(@"Path: %@", aFile);

    ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];

    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[[NSURL alloc]initFileURLWithPath:aFile]];

    [library writeImageDataToSavedPhotosAlbum:data metadata:nil completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error) {

        NSLog(@"Success at %@", [assetURL path] );
    }];
```

}];

It uses the library as I mentioned in my solution before  http://jitsik.com/wordpress/?p=208

How to verify:

**Step 01:** Run the demo project.

**Step 02:** As directed by the application add 2 images and click Export.

**Step 03:** Now check the camera roll you will find the created gif.

**Previous:**

GIF is a proprietary format, so you would need a 3rd party lib to save it.

check following link: http://jitsik.com/wordpress/?p=208

Comment: I've created a bounty if you can show me a sample of how this could be used to saved to camera roll?

Comment: While I found a solution myself, I may resort to this if I cannot cut the size of the GIF down enough to not crash on larger files.

Comment: ALAssetsLibrary is deprecated - is there a more updated version?

Answer (score 1):

Has this been updated to work with iOS 9, and the deprecation of ALAssets? I do not see similar calls in PHPhotoLibrary.

Comment: how is this an answer?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an updated answer using PHPhotoLibrary, since ALAssetsLibrary is deprecated.

I used this answer from another user - 陈星旺

[PHPhotoLibrary save a gif data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35374919/phphotolibrary-save-a-gif-data?noredirect=1&lq=1)

```
NSString *exportPath = [NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingString:@"/animated.gif"];
NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:exportPath isDirectory:NO];
NSData * gifData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:fileURL.absoluteString];

[[PHPhotoLibrary sharedPhotoLibrary] performChanges:^{

    PHAssetResourceCreationOptions *options = [[PHAssetResourceCreationOptions alloc] init];
    [[PHAssetCreationRequest creationRequestForAsset]
     addResourceWithType:PHAssetResourceTypePhoto
     data:gifData
     options:options];

} completionHandler:^(BOOL success, NSError * _Nullable error) {

    if (success) {
        NSLog(@"image saved!");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"error saving image - %@", error ? error.localizedDescription : @"");
    }
}];
```

If you needed to download the GIF data from a URL, you could use this:

```
NSData *gifData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:theGIFsURL];
```