# PHPhotoLibrary save a gif data

Tags: objective-c, ios9, nsdata, phphotolibrary

I can't find a similar method to ALAssetsLibrary->writeImageDataToSavedPhotosAlbum in the new PHPhotoLibrary since ALAssetsLibrary deprecated in iOS 9 I can't save GIF probably I'm using this code

```
[[PHPhotoLibrary sharedPhotoLibrary] performChanges:^{
        PHAssetChangeRequest *assetRequest = [PHAssetChangeRequest creationRequestForAssetFromImage:[UIImage imageWithData:gifdata]];
        placeholder = [assetRequest placeholderForCreatedAsset];
        photosAsset = [PHAsset fetchAssetsInAssetCollection:collection options:nil];
        PHAssetCollectionChangeRequest *albumChangeRequest = [PHAssetCollectionChangeRequest changeRequestForAssetCollection:collection
                                                                                                                      assets:photosAsset];
        [albumChangeRequest addAssets:@[placeholder]];
    } completionHandler:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
        if (success)
        {

        }
        else
        {

            NSLog(@"%@", error);
        }
    }];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my issue by creating temp file and using :

> creationRequestForAssetFromImageAtFileURL

Comment: Can you give more detail on how you created a temp file?

Answer (score 8):

I used `NSData` to save the gif image, `ALAssetsLibrary` method `UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum` deprecated after iOS8,The api says we can use
`PHAssetCreationRequest`method `[[PHAssetCreationRequest creationRequestForAsset] addResourceWithType:PHAssetResourceTypePhoto data:data options:options];` to save this gif image data, so you can use url request to save gifs as well

codes are follows:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"1" ofType:@"gif"];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];
[[PHPhotoLibrary sharedPhotoLibrary] performChanges:^{
    PHAssetResourceCreationOptions *options = [[PHAssetResourceCreationOptions alloc] init];
    [[PHAssetCreationRequest creationRequestForAsset] addResourceWithType:PHAssetResourceTypePhoto data:data options:options];
} completionHandler:^(BOOL success, NSError * _Nullable error) {
    NSLog(@"：%d",success);
}];
```

Comment: you should give an explanation why your code solves the problem. Please look at [answer]

Comment: Thanks @陈星旺, this was the solution to my issue also. If you want to post on my question as well, I'll accept it as an answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40370773/how-to-save-gifs-with-the-phphotolibrary

Comment: Hi , I test this at ios 12, it works for me, @GeneCode, did you import `<Photos/Photos.h>` correctly ? or add "Privacy - Photo Library Usage Description" to your info.plist file ?

Answer (score 2):

I've save gif file successfully to Photos Gallery by using Photos Framework

```
PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges ({
    let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: "your file path")
    PHAssetChangeRequest.creationRequestForAssetFromImage(atFileURL: url)
  }) { saved, error in
    if saved {
      print("Your image was successfully saved")
    }
  }
```

Hope this help!