# Saving an animated gif from AppData to photo album - iOS 11

Tags: ios, gif, ios11

How do you save a gif from the Documents or AppData folder (or otherwise known path) to the Photo Album for iOS 11?

Example of a known path: /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/[app uuid]/Documents/filename.gif

[Older versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26301031/save-generated-gif-to-camera-roll/26302597#comment78331338_26302597) of this [question](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/assetslibrary/alassetslibrary) keep referencing deprecated [ALA*](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/assetslibrary/alassetslibrary). How do you do this for iOS 11?

Comment: pls try PHPhotoLibrary, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27008641/save-images-with-phimagemanager-to-custom-album

Comment: thanks! put together a solution based on PHPhotoLibrary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add frameworks foundation and photos

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <Photos/Photos.h>

int saveGifToGallery(const char *path0){

    NSString *path = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:path0];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];
    [[PHPhotoLibrary sharedPhotoLibrary] performChanges:^{
        PHAssetResourceCreationOptions *options = [[PHAssetResourceCreationOptions alloc] init];
        [[PHAssetCreationRequest creationRequestForAsset] addResourceWithType:PHAssetResourceTypePhoto data:data options:options];
    } completionHandler:^(BOOL success, NSError * _Nullable error) {
        NSLog(@"：%d",success);
    }];

    return 1;

}
```