# Objective-C Create gif from given array of images

Tags: objective-c, arrays, animation, animated-gif

how can i create a gif animation from array of images ?

Usecase:
1.) Take images and save into a user folder
2.) Create GIF Animation with the content of the image folder

thx

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33023196/create-a-gif-with-uiimages

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create a gif with UIImages](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33023196/create-a-gif-with-uiimages)