# List all gif files in photo library

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller

I have a requirement in which the user needs to fetch a gif from a list of gif files in library. I tried to fetch both images & Videos without any issue. But when I used `kUTTypeGIF` as media, it crashes with error :

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'No available types for source
>   0'

Here is my code:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import <MobileCoreServices/MobileCoreServices.h>

@interface ViewController ()<UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate>

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

-(IBAction)btnChooseGif:(id)sender {
    UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    imagePicker.delegate = self;
    imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    imagePicker.mediaTypes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:(NSString *)kUTTypeGIF, nil];   // Here is the crash 
    [self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil];
}

-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)info
{

}
@end
```

How can i solve this? And if `kUTTypeGIF` media is not supported here, how can i show the list all gif files to the user for choosing one? I need to display gif files only in the UIImagePickerController

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37934698/how-to-load-animated-gif-from-photo-library

Comment: @DSDharma That is not my issue. I want my app to list all gif files in the image picker itself. The user should be able to see only gif files in the phone for selection

Comment: GIF isn't a valid media type. Allowed media types are `image` and `movie`. You check accepted types with `UIImagePickerController.availableMediaTypes(for: .photoLibrary)`

Comment: Also, as of iOS 11, animated images are grouped in a Smart Album called "`Animated`". So you could use PHAssetCollection to find it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

iOS does not give you an easy way to determine -- while using UIImagePickerController -- what the underlying file format is for the pictures stored in the camera roll.  Apple's philosophy here is that an image should be thought of as a `UIImage` object and that you should not care what the ultimate file format is.

So, since you can not use UIImagePickerController to filter out GIF files.  Here's a couple possibilities for you:

1 )

Once you pick an image, you can determine what kind of file it is.  [Here's an example question that asks how to determine if the image is a PNG or JPEG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11270335/using-uiimagepickercontroller-to-get-image-how-to-know-whether-to-save-png-or).  Once the user picks a file, you'll know whether it's a GIF or a JPEG or a PNG or whatever.

2 )

You could *convert* any UIImage to a `GIF` file. [Here's a question that points to a library that might be able to help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6813208/how-to-convert-png-image-to-gif-in-iphone-programatically).

3 )

You could iterate across the entire camera roll and convert/save those images into your app's documents directory as `GIF` files.  Something that starts [with enumeration found in this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12633843/get-all-of-the-pictures-from-an-iphone-photolibrary-in-an-array-using-assetslibr) and then runs each picture through the ImageIO framework to convert it to a gif file (the code for which I pointed out in solution # 2).  You can then roll your own picker.

p.s. your own code wasn't going to work because, as Nathan pointed out, `gif` is not a media type.  This is a function that points out the available media types:

```
-(IBAction)btnChooseGif:(id)sender {
    NSArray *availableMedia = [UIImagePickerController availableMediaTypesForSourceType: UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary];

    NSLog(@"availableMedia is %@", availableMedia);

    UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    imagePicker.delegate = self;
    imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;

    imagePicker.mediaTypes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:(NSString *)kUTTypeImage, nil];
    [self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you only want to fetch assets from Photos library without picker, you can use `PHFetchResult` for getting array of `PHAsset`. Below is the list of available `MediaType enums` available in `Photos.Framework`:

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, PHAssetMediaType) {
PHAssetMediaTypeUnknown = 0,
PHAssetMediaTypeImage   = 1,
PHAssetMediaTypeVideo   = 2,
PHAssetMediaTypeAudio   = 3,
} PHOTOS_ENUM_AVAILABLE_IOS_TVOS(8_0, 10_0);
```

You can use it as :

```
PHFetchResult *result = [PHAsset fetchAssetsWithMediaType:PHAssetMediaTypeImage options:nil];
```

and request image from asset as :

```
PHImageManager *manager = [PHImageManager defaultManager];

    PHImageRequestOptions *requestOptions = [[PHImageRequestOptions alloc] init];
    requestOptions.resizeMode   = PHImageRequestOptionsResizeModeExact;
    requestOptions.deliveryMode = PHImageRequestOptionsDeliveryModeHighQualityFormat;
    requestOptions.synchronous = true;

[manager requestImageDataForAsset:asset options:requestOptions resultHandler:^(NSData * _Nullable imageData, NSString * _Nullable dataUTI, UIImageOrientation orientation, NSDictionary * _Nullable info) {
 NSLog(@"Data UTI :%@ \t Info :%@",dataUTI,info);
            }];
```

Hope this will help you!!

Answer (score 3):

In iOS 11 you can get all gif by Smart Album.

```
func getGif() -> PHFetchResult<PHAsset> {
     if let gifCollection = PHAssetCollection.fetchAssetCollections(with: .smartAlbum, subtype: .smartAlbumAnimated, options: nil).firstObject {
        return PHAsset.fetchAssets(in: gifCollection, options: nil)
    }
    return PHFetchResult<PHAsset>()
}
```